# What spells can an Instrument of the Bards actually impose disadvantage on?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, charmed

In light of [the revelation that an Instrument of the Bards requires a spell with a material component to be used](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/120722/36469), what spells can it actually be used on?

Comment: Why is this not closed as too broad?

Comment: @Rogem Because there is a very specific answer to this.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [November 2018 DMG errata](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DMG-Errata.pdf) replaces the last paragraph of the old description with:

> You can play the instrument while casting a spell that causes any of its targets to be charmed on a failed saving throw, thereby imposing disadvantage on the save. This effect applies only if the spell has a somatic or a material component.

The means that a spell qualifies if all of the following conditions are met:

1. The spell causes the Charmed condition
2. The spell calls for a saving throw which, if failed, inflicts the charm effect
3. The spell has a material and/or somatic component

The [spells meeting these 3 conditions](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells?filter-class=0&filter-search=&filter-condition=2&filter-verbal=&filter-somatic=&filter-material=&filter-concentration=&filter-ritual=&filter-sub-class=&sort=level) currently are:

- *Animal friendship*
- *Charm monster*
- *Charm person*
- *Crown of madness*
- *Dominate beast*
- *Dominate monster*
- *Dominate person*
- *Hypnotic pattern*
- *Modify memory*

Comment: One could be even more specific and say the the spell requires a non-costly material component that is not consumed (since foci cannot replace material components with a cost, or components that are consumed on casting)

Comment: The instrument does also specify that spells cast *from the instrument* or when the instrument is used as a spellcasting focus are affected, but the only spell any version of the instruments offers which causes anyone to be Charmed is... Animal Friendship, again. Access to a few more spells is pretty useful of course but one can't help but feel that this secondary aspect of the instrument's power was not really thought through at all...

Answer (score 9):

As of the [November 2018 DMG Errata](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DMG-Errata.pdf):

> ***Instrument of the Bards (p. 176).*** The final paragraph is replaced with the following: “You can play the instrument while casting a spell that causes any of its targets to be charmed on a failed saving throw, thereby imposing disadvantage on the save. This effect applies only if the spell has a somatic or a material component.”

There is no longer a requirement that the instrument be used as the focus, and it works as long as there is a somatic *or* material component. While the character still needs to be a bard to attune it, it can be used with non-bard spells.

Based on a quick [filter on D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells?filter-class=0&filter-search=&filter-condition=2&filter-verbal=&filter-somatic=&filter-material=&filter-concentration=&filter-ritual=&filter-sub-class=&sort=level), the list appears to be:

- *Animal Friendship*
- *Charm Monster*
- *Charm Person*
- *Crown of Madness*
- *Dominate Beast*
- *Dominate Monster*
- *Dominate Person*
- *Hypnotic Pattern*
- *Modify Memory*

Some of the spells under that same search (not listed above) are there because they cure or suppress the charmed condition. Of those that aren't curatives, a few others don't make muster for use with an *Instrument* for other reasons:

- *Awaken* imposes charmed, but has no save.
- *Compulsion*, *Suggestion*, and *Mass Suggestion* don't actually impose the charmed condition, despite un-charmable people being immune.
- *Geas* only has a verbal component.

*Suggestion* actually doesn't appear at all on that search, but *Mass Suggestion* does. That indicates there may be a problem in the site's indexing functions, so there may be other spells that reference the Charmed condition that aren't being found.

Answer (score -4):

A casting of *hypnotic pattern* that imposes disadvantage on the save is entirely worth it.  A half dozen opponents suddenly becomes effectively one or two, maybe zero.  As powerful as that combo is, what more do you really need?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE. Please take the tour to see how a Q&A site in the SE format is different from a discussion forum.  Also, please take a look at [how to write a good answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).  You've got a good start, please follow through with those guidelines in mind.

Comment: While I don't completely disagree, this doesn't answer the question and feels more like a comment.