# Which features allow me to choose spells from another class as a spell of my own class?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature

For example, the Bard feature Magical Secrets says:

> Choose two spells from any class[...] The chosen spells count as bard spells for you.

I'm looking for a conclusive list of such features. Please note that the Spellcasting feature is not included in this, neither are features that allow you to cast a specific spell a certain number of times per long or short rest.

All official releases.

---

**Motivation:** Being able to cast spells such as Green-Flame Blade or Eldritch Blast are normally exclusive to only a small selection of classes. A feature that would allow, say, a Cleric to cast these spells might open up a ton of new options for character builds that are centered around such a spell.

Comment: Why do you need to know this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Does the fact that the Eldritch Knight and Arcane Trickster get wizard spells count?

Comment: @T.J.L.I often try to build a character around a specific spell, like Green Flame Blade or Eldritch Blast. With the former spell I would be constrained to Sorcerer/Warlock/Wizard, with the latter to Warlock. If I could gain access to these spells as, say, a Cleric spell, I could then cast them with Wisdom as Spell Casting Ability, which allows for a far less Multiple Attribute Dependant Character while opening up far more options.

Comment: @goodguy5 sure!

Comment: @goodguy5 hold up! those two features are actually the Spellcasting feature itself, which initially grants you the ability to cast spells. However, if you read the question's body again, you will see that I am actually looking for features that contain "[the new spells] count as [your class] spells for you", in word or spirit.

Comment: @PoeticallyPsychotic: Please do not answer in the comments. Answer below in an answer. Use comments only for improving the question. See [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments) for our policy.

Comment: So you are looking for features which allow you to put a spell or spells of any other class on your spell list? Or are you looking as well for features which allow you to put spells from only specific classes (or individual spells) into your class list?

Comment: @Rubiksmoose well to be honest, my original goal was to build a character that could add their Spellcasting ability modifier multiple times to either GFB or EB, in order to "exploit" the fact that adding ability modifiers to cantrip damage makes them pretty powerful. The obvious choice would be Dragon Bloodline Sorcerer or Warlock with Agonizing Blast, but I was trying to find other, equally viable builds, preferably non-sorcerer or -warlock ones, like a cleric or bard. But it seems I fell into the trap (again) of trying to ask a generic question, when the original one would have worked better

Comment: @ammut it's a very common trap. Good news is that you can always ask your real question at any time!

Comment: I didn't see this was put on hold. I don't think it's too broad - it's limited to features where you choose spells and the chosen spells count as your class's spells. I think I was fairly thorough and only found 8 features, all clear cut cases.

Comment: nevertheless, I disagree with the "too broad" reason. I've started writing an answer myself and the List of features which apply can't be bigger than maybe 15, which is pretty manageable in my opinion.

Comment: Part of the trouble is that any such list becomes obsolete as soon as relevant new material is released. That’s one reason a question can be “too broad”: it’s a list that potentially needs endless updates.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie That doesn't seem to be a problem for [this q&a](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/120757/25757), judging by the number of votes, despite suffering from that predicament just the same.

Comment: @ammut Questions are judged individually, not relative to others. Also, votes are orthogonal to whether a question should be open or closed—people can upvote for any reason they want, so there’s nothing to stop off topic or other questions with issues from having a high score but still being closed. Also, I’m not laying down the law here—I haven’t voted or used mod powers—I’m giving information. Trying to disprove me won’t do anything.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I hadn't actually looked at what qualifies for "too broad"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Bard

- **Magical Secrets - Level 10, 14, 18 - PHB p54**
  Choice of any two spells.
- **Additional Magical Secrets (College of Lore) - Level 6 - PHB p55**
  Choice of any two spells.

### Cleric

- **Arcane Initiate (Arcana Domain) - Level 1 - SCAG p125**
  Choice of two Wizard cantrips.
- **Arcane Mastery (Arcana Domain) - Level 17 - SCAG p126**
  Choice of four Wizard spells (one each of 6th, 7th, 8th, and 9th level).

### Sorcerer

- **Divine Magic (Divine Soul) - Level 1 - XGE p50**
  Whenever you replace or learn a sorcerer spell, choose from
  the cleric or sorcerer spell list.

### Warlock

- **Pact of the Tome - Level 3 - PHB p108**
  Choice of any three cantrips.
- **Book of Ancient Secrets (Eldrich Invocation) - Level 3 (earliest) - PHB p110**
  Choice of any two ritual spells.

---

There are other methods for gaining spells not normally on your class's spell list that don't meet the question's criteria:

- Subclass features that give always prepared spells sometimes give spells not on the class's spell list, but you do not choose the spells
- Racial features always specify the spell modifier independent of the character's class
- Spells gained from Feats are treated as spells of the class whose list they're on

---

Given the stated intent in the comments, I'd recommend a Greenflame Blade Arcana Cleric, who adds their Wisdom modifier to both damage rolls at level 8.

Comment: hey, thanks a lot! I took the liberty of rewriting the first part, If you don't like it, feel free to reject!

Comment: There's an Unearthed Arcana option that allows this too; the Lore Mastery wizard  archetype has a class feature that allows you to try to cast any spell from any class (that you have spell slots for). Might be worth including... although it doesn't actually let you learn the spell like your other suggestions...

Comment: I believe the "All official releases" clause would disqualify playtest content. If not then I think that's close enough to work for this