# Is there a way (other than using a wish spell) for a Wizard to cast Ranger spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Using a [wish](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish) spell you can duplicate any other spell of 8th level or lower.

However..

That's a pretty high lv spell for gaining the use of a 1-5 level Ranger spell.
I couldn't find a version of limited wish. And the feat [Magic Initiate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/magic-initiate) doesn't seem to apply to Ranger's spells.

Is there another way to cast 1 or 2 Ranger spells without dipping into the Ranger class? Specifically I am looking at [Conjure Barrage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/conjure-barrage) and [Swift Quiver](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/swift-quiver).  Mostly because I think it would be cool to launch a ton of darts like a Naruto style Ninja...and it would be unexpected from my wizard.

Worth noting we only use the hardcover books.  No UA or 3rd party stuff please.

Comment: TBH a wizard using an AoE damage spell is not that unusual. So while visually it might be strange, it won't give you any tactical advantage.

Comment: I'm looking for "neeto" expressions at the table , not anything tactical really.  I just thought it would be a cool looking surprise.

Comment: What would be the point of multi-classing or playing with other classes if any individual can do any class's specialties?

Comment: @Cedric it's 2 spells dood and neither are special features.

Comment: No, you don't get it.  As soon as you allow it for one, you have to allow it on all -- for the sake of consistency of all other players.

Comment: No you don't.  DMs don't "have" to do anything and are perfectly able to make exceptions.  There are even rules for it in the dmg.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *CHANGING SPELL LISTS
>
> **Modifying a class's spell list usually has little effect on
> a character's power** but can change the flavor of a class
> significantly. In your world, paladins might not swear
> their oaths to ideals, but instead swear fealty to powerful
> sorcerers. To capture this story concept, you could build
> a new paladin spell list with spells meant to protect
> their masters, drawn from the sorcerer or wizard lists.
> Suddenly, the paladin feels like a different class.
> Be cautious when changing the warlock spell list.
> Since warlocks regain their spell slots after a short rest,
> they have the potential to use certain spells more times
> in a day than other classes do. *

DMG pg 285. Emphasis mine

So with your DM's permission, a wizard could have easy access to the ranger spells you want, with little or no change to balance

Comment: And given the two spells OP has in mind, I'd say absolutely go for it, they're not that strong, and in the case of Conjure Barrage its just a reflavor from about half of the regular 3rd level spells with the 3d8 damage and a dex save.

Answer (score 7):

This'll only work if you have a Ranger in your party (or you know a friendly one who is willing to help out from time to time) but a Ring of Spell Storing allows anyone to cast anything from the Ring.

The only thing is the Ring needs to be loaded with spells from time to time, which is why you need a friendly Ranger to refuel your spells.

It won't allow you to use your own spell slots though.

Answer (score 1):

The Bard's [Magical Secrets feature](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/bard#MagicalSecrets-592) allows them to learn spells from any class. You can use it to learn Conjure Barrage and/or Swift Quiver at level 10, or at level 6 if you choose the College of Lore archetype.

If you just want to launch darts like Naruto, you could refluff Magic Missile to have it be shuriken instead of magical missiles. Or find something else to refluff.

If you can convince your DM, there was a UA School of Lore Mastery for Wizard that lets you cast from any spell list once per long rest, at level 14. Not much better than using Wish, but definitely better.

[Here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/139427/which-features-allow-me-to-choose-spells-from-another-class-as-a-spell-of-my-own)'s a complete list of options for learning spells from other lists. That said, only Magical Secrets will work for you, and there are no archetypes I know of that include those spells in their modified lists either. Other than that you are out of luck.

Comment: While this is true, I think this answer would be improved by explaining how this option compares with dipping into Ranger.

Comment: @kviiri OP already said they didn't want to dip into ranger though

Comment: Unrelated comment to above, one can get magical secrets earlier if one chooses the College of Lore (6th level instead of 10th)

Comment: @kviiri good point.

Comment: Yes, but they presumably have a reason for that. Providing analysis comparing with the other option helps them assess your solution based on what they already know about the ranger dip. (A likely reason is the relative expense of multiclassing, and a 10-level bard dip is even worse)

Comment: @kviiri without knowing the reasons why they don't want a ranger dip I don't think there's any meaningful analysis to be performed. For all I know they might say "I just don't like ranger", equally they could say "I don't want to dip anything at all".

Comment: However you wish, however I think there would be only benefit from the comparison, seeing that the alternative is another expensive dip.

Comment: I don't want to give up access to 9th lv wizard spells and wanted to keep him a pure wizard.  So dips in any class won't help.  I appreciate the thought tho. I do like the magic missile idea.  As a last resort...

Comment: @SamLacrumb UA Lore Wizard may be a good bet then, if you can convince your DM. It only saves you a few levels, but it will save you your 9th level slot too.