# Multiclass spell casting and spell modifiers

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, multi-classing, spellcasting

I know that you use your spellcasting modifier from the class you gained the spell from.

However, for something like Tempest Domain cleric gaining the use of *thunderwave* from their subclass (automatically prepared as a domain spell), and as a multiclass with sorcerer who can also use *thunderwave* normally (if they want to learn the spell), can I use my Charisma instead of Wisdom as my spellcasting modifier?

Comment: Related: "[Can a multiclass character use either of its spellcasting modifiers for spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/132854)"

Comment: I assume that in this scenario, you haven't actually learned the spell as a sorcerer, and only have it prepared as a Tempest cleric (automatically, since it's a domain spell)? So, in essence, you're asking "As a multiclass spellcaster, if I have a spell known/prepared from class A but the spell is also on class B's list, can I use spellcasting ability B to cast it?" I've also edited out your secondary question about what spellcasting focus you can use; if you want to ask that, you should do so as a separate question.

Comment: Also: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No

You cast each spell from the class that it comes from.  It doesn't matter that the spell is on more than one of your classes spell lists.
The rule for this is on p164 in the Player's Handbook relating to multiclassing under [Spells Known and Prepared](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/customization-options#Spellcasting).

Comment: Why I don't understand the downvote to this as I believe this is correct, it would be helpful to include the full ruling in your answer, rather than just cite it.

Comment: I was speciffically told not to include quoted text for copyright reasons.  Honestly at this point I don't know what to do.  Half the community downvotes if I quote text the other half downvotes if I don't.  ;/

Comment: If what you quote is freely and legally available text such as what's found [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/customization-options) I can't see why somebody would downvote it

Comment: That sounds very frustrating. The best suggestion I have is to try to quote only smallish snippets of rules, like a couple of sentences at a time. But I've quoted from even non-free sources and still been ok, so I can only assume it's _how much_ you quote that might have been what others have complained about.

Comment: I looked at all of your answers; 7 had downvotes, only [1 of which](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/164908/41726) quoted the text, and I don't believe the downvotes were as a result of that. Trust me when I say that in almost every case, as long as your answer isn't *just* a quote from the text, it is better to cite relevant text from the source.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a link to the relevant rules section from D&D Beyond. I also added a couple words helping to clarify that you're referring to the "Spells Known and Prepared" section of the Multiclassing rules and not the similarly named section in the general rules of spellcasting :)

Comment: It might be worth further clarifying that it *would* be possible to cast a given spell using either class's modifier if that spell is concurrently known and prepared by both classes.